# Not displayed the main application panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm very new in Sencha. When I run my app my main panel doesn't show, only NestedList. Browser shows the following message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getId' of undefined

I don't know how to fix it. I will glad of any hint. 
[this is my app](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#VovtL#o7GJJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things you should modify to get your application works:

- Remove `fullscreen: true` config as it breaks your app layout, because it's not the outer-most component of your applcation.
- Remove `this.detailCard` from `setItems` in your split view since it is **not defined** and **not compulsory to be defined**. So: `this.setItems([this.nestedList]);` is enough.
- Add `layout: 'card'` to your split view config.

I've tested and it worked well. Hope it helps you.